# Python Project in VSCode: How to save and restore full VSCode environment configuration?

Tags: python, docker, visual-studio-code, pytest, python-poetry

I have software products built in Python, each of which has its own git repository and each of which runs in its own Docker container.

The development container can run locally or remotely, and I use VisualStudio Code (VSCode v1.73.1) as my development environment, and it connects to the container and lets me develop and test the code in the container. I am able to use the VSCode environment to get a terminal into the Docker container, and I use Poetry for package management and the Python virtual environment, and Pytest and the VSCode plugins for Python for testing, including code coverage via Pylance and the Coverage Gutters extensions.

Setting up VSCode for this is tedious and very error-prone. There is a lot of "hit and miss" before I get the environment just right. I have to install extensions for VSCode for things like remote servers, Docker containers, extensions for the plugins, and configurations to choose the right version of Python for my testing environment, along with Pylance and Coverage Gutters. If I ever put away my VSCode environment for one product for a few months because I'm working on something else, I have to go through the pain of setting up everything from scratch and by hand.

On the flip side, if I'm working on a project for which its VSCode is configured properly, and my machine has to restart, the environment is recreated when I start up VSCode again.  This tells me that there exists configuration data somewhere which tells VSCode the state to which it should restore itself.

I would like to be able to store this configuration data in the git repository itself so that as soon as I open the project folder in VSCode, my entire configuration comes up. This would include all local extensions, extensions for containers, and configuration for the local environment and extensions. Barring that, if I could go into my repository, edit a file or two (perhaps to point to a root directory, a remote machine and a container), and then start up VSCode, that would be good. I am currently able to save some settings which work. There is a file in `~project_root/.vscode/settings.json` which looks like this:

```json
{
    "python.testing.pytestArgs": [
        "tests",
        "--cov-report=xml",
        "--cov=src/project"
    ],
    "python.testing.pytestEnabled": true,
    "python.formatting.provider": "black",
    "python.analysis.extraPaths": [
        "./src/project"
    ],
}
```

There are no other files in `~project_root/.vscode/`.

**QUESTIONS:**

1. How and where in my git repository can I store the full configuration for the environment besides `~project_root/.vscode/`?
2. When VSCode starts up, how can I tell VSCode to get access to the full environment from the saved configuration?

I appreciate any guidance I can get.

Comment: What is your desired effect? Vscode takes the opened folder as the workspace, and the `.vscode\settings.json` under the workspace is the setting of the current workspace, and the configurations in it are only valid for the current workspace. What other configuration do you want?

Comment: My `settings.json` file only has settings for Python testing, formatting, and analysis (code coverage). I don't have any settings for extensions required for the workspace, or which Python interpreter should VSCode use (e.g. one choice comes from the base Docker image, another comes from Poetry venv and there are a couple of others).

Given that a restarted VSCode takes me to that environment, I would expect that it is stored in configuration files somewhere.

Comment: Does the problem still exist? Any updates?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is similar to [here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/116740). You can try the vscode [Insider](https://code.visualstudio.com/insiders/) version, where the [Settings Profiles](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_69#_settings-profiles) feature is provided.

For setting a specific python interpreter, you can use the following settings in ***settings.json*** to point to the default interpreter.

```
"python.defaultInterpreterPath": "<path_to_python.exe>"
```

In addition, vscode will use the interpreter last selected for this workspace by default every time the workspace is opened.